# Scala: function declaration when doing currying

Tags: scala

I am learning Scala and I don't quite understand:

1. why the code sum1 can't be rewritten by sum2?
2. why in sum1, a and b automatically know (Int,Int) correspond to a and b?

Thanks in advance.

```
    def sum1 (f: Int => Int) : (Int, Int) => Int = {
      def sumF(a:Int, b:Int) : Int = {
        if (a > b) 0
      else f(a) + sumF(a + 1, b)
      }
      sumF
    }

    def sum2 (f: Int => Int, Int, Int) : Int = {
      def sumF(a:Int, b:Int) : Int = {
        if (a > b) 0
        else f(a) + sumF(a + 1, b)
      }
      sumF
    }
```

Comment: does sum2 compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It's because `sum1` and `sum2` have different interfaces: `sum1` is `(Int => Int) => ((Int, Int) => Int)` and `sum2` is `(Int => Int, Int, Int) => Int`. I.e. `sum1` returns function that accepts two integers and returns an integer. But `sum2` returns just an integer value, not a function.
2. Your `sumF` function equal to a lambda function

   ```
   val sumF: (Int, Int) => Int = (a: Int, b: Int) => {
       if (a > b)
           0
       else
           f(a) + sumF(a + 1, b)
   }
   ```

   You can see it if you try to save `sumF` into value (it would look like `val tmp: (Int, Int) => Int = sumF`)

Comment: hey, thank you for the quick answer. could you be more clear why sum1 returns the function? in fact it returns a value just like sum2 does

Comment: I mean if we use sum1(x=>x)(3,5) it returns a value not a function

Comment: `sum1(x=>x)` result is a function `(Int, Int) => Int`. And `sum1(x=>x)(3,5)` equals to `sum1(x=>x).apply(3,5)`

Comment: You apply function `sum1` to lambda `x=>x` and then you apply the result function to arguments `(3,5)`

Comment: ok but x => x and 3, 5 are all parameters for me, so we have 3 parameters here and a function sum1 which takes 3 parameters and gives back a integer (8) ?

Comment: They are. But 3,5 are parameters of the result function, not `sum1`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184820/discussion-between-brest1007-and-aleksey-isachenkov).

Comment: I think you might learn from this by looking into courses and books that teaches scala. It seems the scala syntax might be what is confusing you. I find it very confusing sometimes myself. Strongly recommend looking into the syntax and function declerations.